# Win32 PHP extension development

Tags: php, dll, module, php-extension

What are first steps creating a loadable DLL module extension for PHP to create native support for my own library on Windows?

Would it require re-compiling PHP on windows? What are the tools needed? I don't want to have to use exec and the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q. Would it require re-compiling PHP on windows?
A. Not necessarily, but it is the simplest way.

The command line is your best friend (apple, after years of GUI improved MACOS by ... readding the shell back)

I would try the following:

A. Setup a [mingw-msys](http://www.mingw.org/) build system on win.
B. Follow [PHP Extension Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php):
1. Download [PHP Source code](http://www.php.net/downloads.php)
2. [Build PHP for Extension Development](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.environment.php) using the above MSYS
3. Generate a extension skeleton using [ext_skel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.skeleton.php) your extension will reside in ext/ directory
4. Edit the [config.w32](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.configwin.php) (is a javascript macro system for Makefile generation similar to m4)
...
Continue by following these:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php
http://talks.somabo.de/200610_zend_conf_php_extension_development.pdf

Comment: That's totally wrong. mingw will not work, it relies on VC6 crt which we don't support anymore. Also the compiler itself is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

See for the basic steps to compile PHP or PHP extensions:

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: even today, this is the best answer